# How to specify multiple patterns for isort skip-glob?

Tags: python, isort

How do you tell the Python `isort` utility to ignore **multiple** folder/file patterns using the `--skip-glob` command line option?

Skipping a single pattern works, e.g.

```
isort --skip-glob="**/migrations" .                  # this works
```

However, I'd like to do something like (similar to what I can do with `black --exclude`):

```
isort --skip-glob="**/migrations|docs|libraries" .   # this doesn't work
```

.
I tried the separators "," and "|".

Using `--extend-skip-glob` instead also doesn't work (and while the [documentation here](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#skip-glob) has an example of specifying multiple files in a config file, it doesn't state how to do that on the command line)

Comment: Can you not pass `--skip-glob` multiple times?
E.g. `isort --skip-glob=**/migrations --skip-glob=docs`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the intended way to go, but I finally used a combination of `--skip-glob` and multiple `--extend-skip-glob` parameters, like so:

```
isort --skip-glob="**/migrations" \
      --extend-skip-glob="docs" \
      --extend-skip-glob="libraries" \
      .
```